# Dollar sign in function call in Java using Spark SQL

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following code (Java with Spark SQL) -

```
    import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col;
    ...

    System.out.println("=== Filtering records with average age more than 20 ===");
    Dataset<Row> result = df.filter(col("age").$less(20));
```

I never met a function call in Java that starts with a dollar.
Tried googling it but my best guess so far is that it's a result of a Java calling Scala code (but in Scala source code there is no $less function)

Could you please provide a solid explanation for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because every allowable symbol in Scala’s method syntax has a corresponding translation of the form “$trans“. so for your question there is a method in scala that called `<` and the corresponding method in java will be `$less`

Other operators will be compiled to:

```
╔═══════════════════╦══════════════╗
║ Scala Operator    ║ Compiles To  ║
╠═══════════════════╬══════════════╣
║=                  ║$eq           ║
║>                  ║$greater      ║
║<                  ║$less         ║
║+                  ║$plus         ║
║-                  ║$minus        ║
║*                  ║$times        ║
║/                  ║$div          ║
║!                  ║$bang         ║
║@                  ║$at           ║
║#                  ║$hash         ║
║%                  ║$percent      ║
║^                  ║$up           ║
║&                  ║$amp          ║
║~                  ║$tilde        ║
║?                  ║$qmark        ║
║║                  ║$bar          ║
║\                  ║$bslash       ║
║:                  ║$colon        ║
╚═══════════════════╩══════════════╝
```

more information about this can be found here:
http://www.codecommit.com/blog/java/interop-between-java-and-scala

Answer (score 3):

The answer can be found here - http://www.codecommit.com/blog/java/interop-between-java-and-scala

> #### Operators are Methods
>
> One of the most obvious differences between Java and Scala is that
>   Scala supports operator overloading.  In fact, Scala supports a
>   variant of operator overloading which is far stronger than anything
>   offered by C++, C# or even Ruby.  With very few exceptions, any symbol
>   may be used to define a custom operator.  This provides tremendous
>   flexibility in DSLs and even your average, every-day API (such as
>   `List` and `Map`).
>
> Obviously, this particular language feature is not going to translate
>   into Java quite so nicely.  Java doesn’t support operator overloading
>   of any variety, much less the über-powerful form defined by Scala. 
>   Thus, Scala operators must be compiled into an entirely non-symbolic
>   form at the bytecode level, otherwise Java interop would be
>   irreparably broken, and the JVM itself would be unable to swallow the
>   result.
>
> A good starting place for deciding on this translation is the way in
>   which operators are declared in Scala: as methods.  Every Scala
>   operator (including unary operators like `!`) is defined as a method
>   within a class:
>
> ```scala
> abstract class List[+A] {
>   def ::[B >: A](e: B) = ...
>
>   def +[B >: A](e: B) = ...
> }
> ```
>
> Since Scala classes become Java classes and Scala methods become Java
>   methods, the most obvious translation would be to take each operator
>   method and produce a corresponding Java method with a
>   heavily-translated name.  In fact, this is exactly what Scala does. 
>   The above class will compile into the equivalent of this Java code:
>
> ```scala
> public abstract class List<A> {
>   public <B super A> List<B> $colon$colon(B e) { ... }
>
>   public <B super A> List<B> $plus(B e) { ... }
> }
> ```
>
> Every allowable symbol in Scala’s method syntax has a corresponding
>   translation of the form “*`$trans`*“.  A list of supported
>   translations is one of those pieces of documentation that you would
>   expect to find on the Scala website.  However, alas, it is absent. 
>   The following is a table of all of the translations of which I am
>   aware:
>
> ```
> ┌────────────────┬─────────────┐
> │ Scala Operator │ Compiles To │
> ├────────────────┼─────────────┤
> │  =             │  $eq        │
> ├────────────────┼─────────────┤
> │  >             │  $greater   │
> ├────────────────┼─────────────┤
> │  <             │  $less      │
> ├────────────────┼─────────────┤
> │  +             │  $plus      │
> ├────────────────┼─────────────┤
> │  -             │  $minus     │
> ├────────────────┼─────────────┤
> │  *             │  $times     │
> ├────────────────┼─────────────┤
> │  /             │  div        │
> ├────────────────┼─────────────┤
> │  !             │  $bang      │
> ├────────────────┼─────────────┤
> │  @             │  $at        │
> ├────────────────┼─────────────┤
> │  #             │  $hash      │
> ├────────────────┼─────────────┤
> │  %             │  $percent   │
> ├────────────────┼─────────────┤
> │  ^             │  $up        │
> ├────────────────┼─────────────┤
> │  &             │  $amp       │
> ├────────────────┼─────────────┤
> │  ~             │  $tilde     │
> ├────────────────┼─────────────┤
> │  ?             │  $qmark     │
> ├────────────────┼─────────────┤
> │  |             │  $bar       │
> ├────────────────┼─────────────┤
> │  \             │  $bslash    │
> ├────────────────┼─────────────┤
> │  :             │  $colon     │
> └────────────────┴─────────────┘
> ```
>
> Using this table, you should be able to derive the “real name” of any
>   Scala operator, allowing its use from within Java.  Of course, the
>   idea solution would be if Java actually supported operator overloading
>   and could use Scala’s operators directly, but somehow I doubt that
>   will happen any time soon.

**** This answer was published by someone but for some reason removed (would love if the orig owner of the answer could republish it)

Comment: my answer was deleted because it was a snapshot